# Yacc Scope Problem

Tags: bison

So I looked around for an answer to this, but the only thing I could gather was that i was having a scope problem.

The error reads ch3-05.y:54: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘{’ token

Here is my code verbatim

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ch3hdr2.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
%}

%union {
    double dval;
    struct symtab *symp;
}
%token <symp> NAME
%token <dval> NUMBER
%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc UMINUS

%type <dval> expression
%%
statement_list  : statement '\n'
                | statement_list statement '\n'
            ;

statement   : NAME '=' expression   {$1->value = $3;}
        | expression        { printf("= %g \n", $1); }

expression  :   expression '+' expression { $$ = $1 + $3;}
    |   expression '-' expression { $$ = $1 - $3;}
    |   expression '*' expression { $$ = $1 * $3;}
    |   expression '/' expression { 
            if($3 == 0.0)
                yyerror("divide by zero");
            else
                $$ = $1 / $3;
            }
    |   '_' expression %prec UMINUS {$$ = -$2;}
    |   '(' expression ')'  { $$ = $2;}
    |   NUMBER
    |   NAME        {$$ = $1->value; }
    |   NAME '(' expression ')' {
            if($1 ->funcptr)
                $$ = ($1->funcptr) ($3);
            else {
                printf("%s not a function\n", $1->name);
                $$ = 0.0;
                }
            }
    ;
%%

struct symtab *
symlook(s) 
char *s;
{ // this is where the error is
    char *p;
    struct symtab *sp;

    for(sp = symtab; sp < &symtab[NSYMS]; sp++){
        if(sp -> name && !strcmp(sp->name, s))
            return sp;

    if(!sp->name) {
        sp->name = strdup(s);
        return sp;
        }
}
yyerror("TOO MANY SYMBOLS");
exit(1);
}

addfunc(name, func)
char *name;
double (*func)();
{
    struct sumtab *sp = symlook(name);
    sp->funcptr = func;
    }

main()
{
    extern double sqrt(), exp(), log();

addfunc("sqrt", sqrt);
addfunc("exp", exp);
addfunc("log", log);
yyparse();
    }
```

I've been staring at the screen but nothing as worked yet. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Also, I get a few more errors later on, but I think it may be because I haven't resolved this one yet.

Here is what I have for ch3hdr2.h

```
#define NSYMS 20 /* max number of symbols */

struct symtab {
    char *name;
    double (*funcptr)();
    double value;
} symtab [NSYMS];

struct symtab *symlook();
```

Comment: You should not be writing/using code that uses non-prototype function declarations.  Where did that code come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo `struct sumtab` instead of `struct symtab` at in `addfunc()`.

Otherwise, the code compiles under GCC (4.6.0 on MacOS X 10.6.7) with some minor wittering.

You can get an error similar to the one you get if you compile with G++ instead of GCC:

```
xx.tab.c: In function ‘int yyparse()’:
xx.tab.c:1252:16: error: ‘yylex’ was not declared in this scope
xx.y:32:41: error: ‘yyerror’ was not declared in this scope
xx.y:42:91: error: too many arguments to function
xx.tab.c:1432:35: error: ‘yyerror’ was not declared in this scope
xx.tab.c:1578:35: error: ‘yyerror’ was not declared in this scope
xx.y: At global scope:
xx.y:52:9: error: ‘symtab* symlook’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
ch3hdr2.h:9:16: error: previous declaration of ‘symtab* symlook()’
xx.y:52:9: error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope
xx.y:54:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
```

That's because the function style is invalid in C++ even though it is 'OK' (but archaic) in C.

Which compiler are you actually using - on which platform?

---

After fixing the typo, when I add `#include <stdlib.h>` to the list of headers and use either GCC 4.2.1 (XCode 3) or GCC 4.6.0, then the code compiles with warnings, but it compiles:

```
yacc  ch3-05.y
/usr/bin/gcc -g -I/Users/jleffler/inc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes \
         -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition   -c y.tab.c
In file included from ch3-05.y:3:
ch3hdr2.h:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
ch3hdr2.h:9: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
y.tab.c: In function ‘yyparse’:
y.tab.c:1253: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yylex’
ch3-05.y:33: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yyerror’
ch3-05.y: At top level:
ch3-05.y:54: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
ch3-05.y: In function ‘symlook’:
ch3-05.y:55: warning: old-style function definition
ch3-05.y:56: warning: unused variable ‘p’
ch3-05.y: At top level:
ch3-05.y:73: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’
ch3-05.y:73: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
ch3-05.y: In function ‘addfunc’:
ch3-05.y:74: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
ch3-05.y:75: warning: old-style function definition
ch3-05.y:78: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
ch3-05.y: At top level:
ch3-05.y:81: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’
ch3-05.y:81: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
ch3-05.y: In function ‘main’:
ch3-05.y:81: warning: old-style function definition
```

The GCC 4.6.0 output is interesting - much easier to see what triggers each warning:

```
In file included from ch3-05.y:3:0:
ch3hdr2.h:5:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
ch3hdr2.h:9:8: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
y.tab.c: In function ‘yyparse’:
y.tab.c:1253:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yylex’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
ch3-05.y:33:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yyerror’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
ch3-05.y: At top level:
ch3-05.y:53:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
ch3-05.y: In function ‘symlook’:
ch3-05.y:53:1: warning: old-style function definition [-Wold-style-definition]
ch3-05.y:56:11: warning: unused variable ‘p’ [-Wunused-variable]
ch3-05.y: At top level:
ch3-05.y:72:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [enabled by default]
ch3-05.y:72:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
ch3-05.y: In function ‘addfunc’:
ch3-05.y:74:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
ch3-05.y:72:1: warning: old-style function definition [-Wold-style-definition]
ch3-05.y: At top level:
ch3-05.y:80:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [enabled by default]
ch3-05.y:80:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
ch3-05.y: In function ‘main’:
ch3-05.y:80:1: warning: old-style function definition [-Wold-style-definition]
ch3-05.y: In function ‘addfunc’:
ch3-05.y:78:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Comment: I've been using bison and flex on Mac OSX 10.6.6

Comment: Is there a way to get GCC 4.6.0 on Macports?

Comment: @David: Dunno - haven't looked; I built my own yesterday afternoon, and it took maybe a couple of hours.  It does require GMP, MPFR and MPC libraries to be built; they're all routine builds too.  That part took longest, probably, simply because the libraries had to be configured, built, checked, installed in sequence.  Once I'd got those in place, the main GCC build was set in motion and completed in its own time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't look at the yacc code. Open up the generated `y.tab.c` file (or whatever you've called it) and look at the C code.

That will be a better indicator of what the problem is since *that* is what the compiler is trying to process. Sometimes the `#file` and `#line` constructs that yacc puts into the C code just get in the way.

My first thoughts are that it has something to do with the archaic function "prototypes". You may want to consider re-doing these like:

```
struct symtab *symlook (char *s) { // this is hopefully where the error isn't :-)
: : :
```

Failing that, I often see errors similar to that where the definition of a return type is not in existence. Make sure that `struct symtab` has been fully defined at that point.

Then, if it still doesn't work, post the generated C source code (including header files) as well as the yacc code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is probably the `struct sumtab` in addfunc.  Otherwise, its likely something wrong in the ch3hdr2.h header file or some other header file it includes...

Comment: I edit the sumtab to be symtab, but I'm still getting the same problem. I'll include the ch3hdr2 file so you folks can look at it.